# Wordpress・Search＆Fillter Proと、Advanced Custom Fieldで価格の安い順、高い順、アルファベット順などに並び替える方法

Tags: wordpress

Wordpress・Search＆Fillter Proと、Advanced Custom Fieldで価格の安い順、高い順、アルファベット順などに並び替える方法をご存知ではないでしょうか？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

https://demo.designsandcode.com/sfpro-woo-mystile/shop/

Comment: 例：order_dir=",asc,desc" order_by=",id,name"  http://docs.designsandcode.com/search-filter/#example-10